# Error converting datatype nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table Data

| Amount1 | Amount2 | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 4.17% |
| A | 500 |  |
|  |  |  |
| 500 | B |  |
| 20 | 100 | 1.67% |

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblData](
    [Amount1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Amount2] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[tblData] ([Amount1], [Amount2]) VALUES (N'100', N'200')
INSERT [dbo].[tblData] ([Amount1], [Amount2]) VALUES (N'A', N'500')
INSERT [dbo].[tblData] ([Amount1], [Amount2]) VALUES (N'', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[tblData] ([Amount1], [Amount2]) VALUES (N'500', N'B')
INSERT [dbo].[tblData] ([Amount1], [Amount2]) VALUES (N'20', N'100')
```

This works fine as expected when I run it on one line

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Concat(CAST((cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))/(cast(Amount2 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%') AS Result
FROM tblData
```

This fails when I run it on whole table

```
SELECT 
    Concat(CAST((cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))/(cast(Amount2 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%') AS Result
FROM tblData
```

Returning the below error message.

> Error converting datatype nvarchar to numeric

Comment: B is a strange number.

Comment: You are trying to cast 'A' and 'B' as decimal ?

Comment: If the data is meant to be numerical, why are you storing it as an `nvarchar` in the first place?

Comment: Yes since it is nvarchar type user already typed Text characters in those fields.  Since the row items are huge I cannot change those texts.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. (I note you have been asked this a number of times now but are still posting images).

Comment: Is there any tool to generate table?

Comment: *"Yes since it is nvarchar type user already typed Text characters in those fields"* That doesn't explain *why* the columns were created as an `nvarchar` in the first place, nor why the application that they were using didn't have validation on the to stop them entering garbage data like the "number" `B`. You *need* to fix the design and quality of your data first.

Comment: Now I restricted it but the table is already updated with 10 Lac rows of data with invalid data types as input which I cant control now.

Comment: Removed the pictures and updated the thread with table data.  Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a text field that's mostly numeric but you can't rely on then instead of

```
cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))
```

you could use

```
try_cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))
```

Which returns Null if the conversion can't be done

I use try_convert but that's just personal preference, they're effectively the same

try_convert(decimal(18,4), Amount1 )

So the start of your statement would look like this

```
case 
when try_cast(Amount1 as decimal(18,4))  is not null --Numeric 
and try_cast(Amount2 as decimal(18,4)) > 0 --Numeric and not zero
then Concat(CAST((try_cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))/(try_cast(Amount2 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if columns are numeric before you do anything:

```
SELECT Amount1
       , Amount2
       , case when isnumeric(Amount1) = 1 and isnumeric(Amount2) = 1 then
Concat(CAST((cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))/(cast(Amount2 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%') 
         else 
null
         end AS "Expected Result"
FROM tblData
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=199f506f3777d0558561d8901a3854f2)

If you have 0's in your data then something like this:

```
SELECT Amount1, Amount2, 
case when isnumeric(Amount1) = 1 and isnumeric(Amount2) = 1 and Amount2 > 0 and Amount1 > 0 then
Concat(CAST((cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))/(cast(Amount2 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%') 
when isnumeric(Amount1) = 1 and isnumeric(Amount2) = 1  and Amount1 = 0 and Amount1 > 0 then
Concat(CAST((cast(1 AS decimal(18,4))/(cast(Amount2 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%') 
when isnumeric(Amount1) = 1 and isnumeric(Amount2) = 1  and Amount1 > 0 and Amount1 = 0 then
Concat(CAST((cast(Amount1 AS decimal(18,4))/(cast(1 AS decimal(18,4))*12))*100 AS decimal(18,2)),'%') 
else 
null
end AS "Expected Result"
FROM tblData
```

[Here is a second demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4aa3d3ae43b0cc0f4d00026702c6fb34)

Comment: "Divide by zero error encountered" error pops up.

Comment: `isnumeric` is a terrible function; don't use it.

Comment: Hi @Larnu "is a terrible function; don't use it." why would help to OP.

Comment: you are never sure in what order the database will proceed, it might be possible that the conversion is tried before your isnumeric function was called. In that case you will still get the same error

Comment: [Avoid IsNumeric](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/sql-prompt-code-analysis-avoid-using-isnumeric-function-e1029)

Comment: Then OP can use TRY_CAST

Comment: Thanks for the revised code.  Now encountered "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar vlaue '20,000' to data type int."

Comment: Until the OP has other garbage data like they have just shown (`N'20,000'`) and they get the same error again, @VBoka . `ISNUMERIC(N'20,000')` returns `1`. `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` are _vastly_ better functions. `ISNUMERIC` simply checks if the value can be converted to *any* of the numerical based data types, not the specific one you might be wanting to convert the value to.